# how to configure UITableViewCell in willDisplayCell method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I am trying to do initial setup of `UITableViewCell` in will display cell but it does not work. can anyone help me out?

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     cell.awtxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]; //i am unable to set this .awtxt is the property outlet in my custom ui table view cell named as "postCell"
}
```

Comment: Did you try to cast your cell as your custom cell? because the method says "cell" is a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: why don't you do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or in `awakeFromNib` of your cell subclass?

Comment: because i heard that configuration type of things should be done in will display method

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37653235/5653015
Note: it's swift answer

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked when I changed the method from `UITableViewCell` to my custom cell.
So just replace the `UITableViewCell` with your custom `postCell`

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(postTableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath // replace "postTableViewCell" with your cell
 {

  cell.awtxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]; //i am unable to set this .awtxt is the property outlet in my custom ui table view cell named as "postCell"

 }
```

Comment: Ok what happens when you have multiple custom prototype cells? How do you cater to all their willDisplayCell methods?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Mike_NotGuilty. I tried what he suggested for my custom/subclass of UITableViewCell called BNRItemCell with the method definition as follows and it works great:

```
//This function is where all the magic happens
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView willDisplayCell:(BNRItemCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set the cells background color
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        UIColor *altCellColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3 alpha:0.5];
        cell.backgroundColor = altCellColor;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:20.0];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount: 0.5];
    [cell.nameLabel setAlpha:0.4];
    [cell.nameLabel setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

You should replace the original method definition with your custom one and try:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView willDisplayCell:(PostCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: how can i use multiple cell in willdisplay method