# Want to redefine willDisplayCell method in Swift. How to redefine class methods

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, oop

I am using certain UI components within my custom cell class and I want to configure those in the willDisplayCell method. The original definition is

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Now using `cell.myTextField.text = "customise"` 
gives out error that cell does not have any component as myTextField

to resolve this I will have to redefine the method to

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: **myCustomCellClass**, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Any leads on how to do this and subsequently how to redefine any present class methods in swift will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is a protocol method with complete implementation logic depending on you. How are you going to re-define it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the parameter type because that would change the interface. You could get away with changing the return type of a method to a subtype but you cannot change method parameter to a subtype.

You have one option really, a dynamic cast:

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   // use as? or as! to cast UITableViewCell to your desired type
}
```

Of course, you can do the same in multiple ways, for example, you can create a redirection method:

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   self.tableView(tableView, willDisplayMyCell: cell as! MyCellClass, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayMyCell myCell: MyCellClass, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   // do something
}
```

and you can abstract that into a subprotocol of `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

}

protocol MyTableViewDelegate : UITableViewDelegate {
    associatedtype CellClass: UITableViewCell

    func tableView(
        tableView: UITableView,
        willDisplayMyCell cell: CellClass,
        forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    }

extension MyTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(
        tableView: UITableView,
        willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
        forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.tableView(tableView, willDisplayMyCell: cell as! CellClass, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }    
}
```

The cool thing about this is that the protocol is reusable, however, it all boils down to `as?` or `as!` dynamic cast.

Comment: So there is no way i can redefine the definition of an existing foundation class method? I am not sure but will posing help in any way to achieve this?

Comment: @Vkharb Of course you can't (btw, it's not a class method, it's an instance method) It doesn't matter whether it's in Foundation or UIKit of if it's your own method. The protocol defines an interface and if you want to change the interface you have to change both sides that use it (that is, `UITableView` implementation). The only thing you can do is to abstract that casting into a helper, you cannot change the interface (method types) without also reimplementing `UITableView`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast cell to your type inside function

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if let myCell = cell as? **myCustomCellClass**
    {
        //perform your code to cell
    }
}
```

Comment: or `guard let cell = cell as? **myCustomCellClass** else { return }`

Answer (score 1):

Сast cell of `UITableViewCell` type to your cell type

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let aCell = cell as? YourCellClass {
        aCell.myTextField.text = "customise"
    }
}
```

Comment: Same answer as mine after 2 minutes. And votedown cast. Really?

Comment: I am sorry, no copy-paste, I guess we were answering at the same time ;)